# Additive Mixed Models: residual check for count response variable

Tags: regression, generalized-linear-model, heteroscedasticity, generalized-additive-model, mgcv

[image]

Hi,
The response variable is the count of daily number of physician visits of one specific disease.(y usually has the value for example of 4,5,6,10...,26).
A standardized residual plot is produced from:

```
> plot(fit$lme)
```

My model :

```
model <- gam(sum ~ s(Time,k=20) + s(RSK,k=10) + as.factor(DOW) 
         data = mydata,family = quasipoisson, method ="REMl")
```

The plot shows the standardized residuals versus fitted values for the fit of my additive mixed model. It seems that it is not reasonable accordance with the model assumptions? But I don't know how to avoid this pattern for the count data.

The QQplot see also below.

############## UPDATES######
############################

Follwing the advices from @Gavin [Rootograms: a new way to assess count models](https://fromthebottomoftheheap.net/2016/06/07/rootograms/), I checked the Rootgram.
[image]

It seems that the issue here is not to choose beween Negative Binomial or Poisson. While the Rootgram from both distribution looks alike.  Both over predicts und under predicts among particular y-value.

The response actually only concretely take several certain values. see the plot of ECDF.

[image]

So my question would be should another model here be adopted like multi-categorial.

if only a small number of response values 1,...,4,5,6,...15... is observed, should we consider model for multi-categorial data (see Tutz, 2000)

Any help would be much appreciated!
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you mean the lines of points, you can't avoid these kinds of patterns; they are due to the integer nature of the response. You could use PIT residuals, but I haven't implemented them {gratia} and which aren't available in {mgcv} either.

As another diagnostic plot, [consider the rootogram](https://fromthebottomoftheheap.net/2016/06/07/rootograms/), which is available in the {countreg} package (on R-Forge) with a rudimentary implementation also available in the development version of {gratia} on GitHub (though you'll likely have to refit using `gam()` as I haven't written methods for `gamm()` fits yet. I would strongly advise you to refit this using `gam()` anyway, to avoid having to fit the model via PQL, which removes many options for model comparison and may not be as robust as using `gam()` and `method = "REML")`.

Comment: Hi Gavin, thanks a lot for the advices! I applyed the Rootogram like you suggested, which bring me another issue: the response only take severval certain values. As I read several books and come across this multi-categorial model als alternative for possion count data, which confused me a lot. Based on this  invariably  patterns and the discrete nature of the response, should I be caucious and take totally different model assumption for the count data?